# Wrong player count in a room socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a lobby system where users can join a room by a lobbbyId. 
This is my client side

```
const socket = io('/chat');
      socket.emit("player-join", {
      name: returnObj.name,
      lobbyId: returnObj.lobbyId
      })
```

And thats how i catch player-join on a server side.

```
socket.on('player-join', data => {
socket.join(data.lobbyId)
console.log(Object.keys(io.sockets.in(data.lobbyId).connected).length)
})
```

So when a user joins room with id `ff05c541-45d5` my `console.log` prints 1. But when another user joins a room with id `18261413-4625` my `console.log` prints 2. The output that I should get is also 1 because there is only 1 user in that room. The counter clearly works wrong. What should I do in order to fix the counter of the players in a certain room.

Edit: When i `console.log(data.lobbyId)` it is different, thus players are connected to different rooms. Ths is the output

```
ff05c541-45d5
1
18261413-4625
2
18261413-4625
3
```

Comment: Have you logged the lobbyId on the server to see if it is the correct lobbyId?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that and they are connecting to the different room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get list of clients joined to room, user `namespace.clients(callback)` [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-clients-callback).

```
socket.on('player-join', data => {
socket.join(data.lobbyId)
io.of('/chat').in(data.lobbyId).clients((err, data) => {
  console.log("=== clients in room: ", data.length); // data is an array of clients 
});
//console.log(Object.keys(io.sockets.in(data.lobbyId).connected).length)
})
```

Comment: Apparently i always get 0 as an output

Comment: My socket is using a default namespace. Use io.of('/chat')